# Disable parenthesis insertion in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The auto insertion of parenthesis can get very annoying.

Say I was typing `object.get` and it suggested `object.getName`, I'd select it and it inserts `object.getName()` and then by habit I type () and I end up with `object.getName()();`

And with `object.setName` it inserts `object.setName(`, so I end up with `object.setName(("object name);`

Is there a way to disable this annoying feature?

Comment: Yes. Change your habits. Don't do work the computer is already doing for you.

Comment: Then its better to use text editor

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to try to get what Intellij IDEA gives. I think that the guys in JetBrains do quite good job.

**About getters**

When you choose some getter it will add it together with braces specially for you and will put the cursor after this because normally you shouldn't have any parameters to the getters. Then you can straight away use some method from the object that you get or just type ; and go for the next line.

**About setters**

In my IDEA (I am using the latest 13.1.4) when I add setter auto insertion adds method together with the braces as well, but puts the cursor between them because you should have a parameter which you are going to set to this object.

Seems to be quite comfortable to use.